# Reversing a list in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python 3, I need to reverse elements in lists given a number (yet to be determined). For example:

```
list1 = edud - will become dude
list2 = mobbed - will become bombed
list3 = edud - remains the same
```

Can only use range and append functions, reverse function is not to be used and needs to be in python loops.  Suggestions??

So far I have this, but it's wrong:

```
def reverse(list, number):
    for i in range (0,length(my_list)-1):
            for num in number:
                if num == number:
                    new_list.append(my_list[i-num])
    return new_list
```

Comment: What is the number? Your sample cases don't mention a number...

Comment: The number isn't actually defined.  I think that it is similar to :def remove_value(my_list,value), for element in my_list: if element != value: new_list.append(element) return new_list.  Suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is a little confusing to me. "Reverse" is to read a list from the ending to the beginning. That said, the reversed version of `mobbed` should be `debbom`. Nevertheless, the easiest way to accomplish this in Python is using [slices](http://techearth.net/python/index.php5?title=Python:Basics:Slices).

The basics:

```
a = 'mother'
a[::-1] = 'rehtom'
a[2:4] = 'th'
a[2:5] = 'the'
```

Any sort of transformation you're trying to do, can be done by slicing and [joining](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) the pieces again

Comment: requirements say we can't slice - have to do this with loops.

Comment: agreed. but our lecturer wants us to do in the append() method using loops.  I can get the lists to reverse fine, but what has me stumped is reversing 3 of 7 elements without splicing.  this is our first semester with using python.